# Terriajs installation in Windows 10

Tags: 3d, terriajs

Getting error while running `gulp` command.

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.17763.1158]
(c) 2018 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

C:\Users\SHASHI>cd C:\Users\SHASHI\Desktop\terra\TerriaMap

C:\Users\SHASHI\Desktop\terra\TerriaMap>npm run gulp

terriajs-map@0.0.1 gulp C:\Users\SHASHI\Desktop\terra\TerriaMap
gulp

[10:25:21] Local gulp not found in ~\Desktop\terra\TerriaMap
[10:25:21] Try running: npm install gulp
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! terriajs-map@0.0.1 gulp: `gulp`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the terriajs-map@0.0.1 gulp script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\SHASHI\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-05-07T04_55_21_870Z-debug.log

C:\Users\SHASHI\Desktop\terra\TerriaMap>
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you haven't installed the dependencies for the project. Within the TerriaMap directory you should run `npm run install` to install all the dependencies (including Gulp).

That said, it is a little unusual to `npm run gulp` in that directory, can you exaplain what you are trying to achieve? There is also an active [Gitter channel](https://gitter.im/TerriaJS/terriajs) if you need other assistance